# how to insert a document to bitbucket using java?

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I can insert a document to bitbucket using git. This is fine.

Now I want to insert some documents to bitbucket using Java code. 
is that possible?
 
do we any other ways to push to bitbucket using some code time to time or something like auto.
provide me some suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could just do a bunch of `Runtime.exec(command)` :P. If you have git installed under PATH and stuff like that.

Comment: @3kings Firstly thank you so much and now i'll research and do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [jgit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/). That offers you a java way to access git repositories. Bitbucket is than just a remote repository. A brief intro on how to use jgit can be found at the answer to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861881/jgit-cannot-find-a-tutorial-or-simple-example)